# create checked exception class in java

Tags: java, exception, checked-exceptions

I am puzzled about creating `checked exception class` in java.

Many article says custom exception can be created by

```
class MyException extends Exception
{
  //constructor defined
}
```

Since RuntimeException is also inherited from `Exception` class.

**Is it not possible to create a class that will cover only Checked Exceptions ?**

Or I need to specify list of checked exceptions

```
class MyException extends IOException
    {
      //constructor defined
    }
```

In above code, there can be a scenario where i would miss certain checked exceptions.

Comment: what does this mean: ***extends IOException, FileNotFoundException*** ?? java doesnt allow multiple inheritance

Comment: You cannot inherit from more than one class but you can catch multiple exceptions with only one statement (introduced in Java 7).

Comment: I mark it by mistake. I meant does extending specific exception is the only possibility ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
class MyException extends IOException,FileNotFoundException
```

is simply not possible in Java. A class can only extend **one** other class.

The point is:

- when you *extend* **Exception** you are creating a checked exception.
- when you *extend* **RuntimeException** you are creating an unchecked exception

That is all there is to this. And yes, you are correct, it is a *bit* awkward that `RuntimeException extends Exception` but is **not** a checked exception. But this fact is basically "baked" into the Java language, and there is nothing you can do about that (besides knowing and accepting).

And as you updated your question - when you do:

```
public class MyException extends IOException
```

then you create a **checked** exception that is *also* an IOException! So to be precise: when you extend `Exception`, or any of the subclasses ob `Exception` (*except* RuntimeException) you are creating a checked exception!

Answer (score 4):

> Is it not possible to create a class that will cover only Checked
>   Exceptions ?

Covering an exception ?

I think that you misunderstand the exception concept.
Any exception that you will create doesn't cover all exception as the exception root class is `Exception` and not your custom exception class.

> In above code, there can be a scenario where i would miss certain
>   checked exceptions.

You want to represent an exception that may wrap any checked exception ? 
So provide a field in your constructor class to associate your exception with any checked exception :

```
public class MyCheckedException extends Exception
{
   public MyCheckedException(Exception causeException){
     super(causeException);
   }
}
```